# MVC Passing a SelectList back to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've lifted the following code from another question because it fits perfectly for the issue I'm having

**Get Action**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register()
{
    var model = new RegistrationViewModel
    {
        Roles = GetRoles()
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? RoleId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label" })
    <div class="col-form-txt">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, Model.Roles, "Select Option", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**PostAction on Controller**

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegistrationViewModel model)
{
      // this is the point where it's failing me!
}
```

Although the model is being passed to the controller from the View, with the RoleId assigned, it's not taking through the `Roles` List with all the available options. How can I get it to carry that through from the View?

I need the list of options to persist through as part of the model so that same model can be entered straight back into a controller without having to populate `Roles` again... if possible...

Comment: Why do you need the available options? You should only be concerned with the selected options in the post back.

Comment: It's MVC framework 472 and I'd like the options list to still be there so I can reuse the model without calling "GetRoles" again

Comment: It just means avoiding another call to the database when technically the info is all still there...

Comment: You could use a hidden field (@Html.HiddenFor) and put the options there as a CSV string. Do keep security in mind as the form can always be tampered with by a malicious user. The server should never trust user input.

Comment: Save the roles in a session or cache instead.

Comment: Yeah I started thinking about the security implications as I was writing my last comment. I think it might be safer to inject the call to get the roles again...